# Get CSS property value of an element on a page from a URL of the same origin

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I would like to get the background color of an element that resides at an external page, in the same domain. I have a <s>working solution</s> first approach, but there must be a better way and I hope that you might point me in the right direction.

**My Approach**

I decided to first load the external page into an iframe:

```
var $page = $('<iframe/>').attr('src', 'http://mydomain.com/page');
```

Then append the iFrame to my current page:

```
$('#iframe-placeholder').append($page);
```

And finally I access the CSS property:

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
  var backgroundColor = $(this).contents().find('#my-element').css('backgroundColor');
});
```

**Downsides of this Approach**

1. It's slow
2. It's asynchronous
3. It doesn't actually works. Returns always `transparent`.

**Question**

Is there a way to get the CSS property of that external page?
I really need the call to be Synchronous and loading the whole page into an iFrame (if that's a solution) is just an overkill.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated...

Comment: All AJAX calls should also be asynchronous. There is a way to make synchronous calls, but it should be avoided because it freezes the page's UI.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I am fine with freezing the UI, as I have a loading gif and a note to the user to be patient. That should be the default behaviour.

Comment: If the style is set externally or requires the page to be loaded in a browser somehow (read javascript), just getting the HTML from a file wont do much good ?

Comment: This is a very strange question. Why not just store this information in a stylesheet and read it from there?

Comment: @adeneo The HTML in the iFrame has the styling from the external CSS file. Shouldn't I be able to get the CSS property? Sorry If I didn't understand your point...

Comment: Nope, not really! If you use an ajax request you get the source from the file, and styles set in external stylesheet are not included.

Comment: @adeneo Interesting to hear that. Thank you for that info. Do you might have any ideas of a possible workaround?

Comment: If it's all on the same domain, just getting the stylesheet with ajax and parsing that could be an option, but a rather complicated one.

Comment: @adeneo Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the page contents asynchronously and working from there?

```
var backgroundColor;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://mydomain.com/page',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(pageData) {
        var page = $(pageData);
        backgroundColor = page.find('#my-element').css('backgroundColor');
    }
});
```

Do note that this is untested code.

Comment: Thank you. Just tested this and I also tested more carefully my original code. Both of them return `transparent` as background color, but in the CSS file the background color is set to #fff.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i understand the temptation of using iframe to load stuff to avert `same origin policy`, but i will like to draw your attention to something else: **[CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)**

Consider the case, where  the site alice.com has some data that the site bob.com wants to access. By supporting CORS requests, alice.com can add a few special response headers that allows bob.com to access the data.

**End-to-End Example :**

```
// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
function getTitle(text) {
  return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest() {
  // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
  var url = 'http://updates.html5rocks.com';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = getTitle(text);
    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

Run the sample and watch the network requests in the browser's debugger to see the actual request being made.

Additionally, you can visit the website i mentioned to get a full understanding of how the methodology works.